# Using RenderedGeometry as Data of Path does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, path, polygon

I want to draw a simple `Path` which uses `RenderedGeometry` of a `Polygon` as `Data`.

```
Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
polygon.Points = new PointCollection { new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 100), new Point(150, 150) };
var path = new Path
{ 
    Data = polygon.RenderedGeometry,
    Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    Fill = Brushes.Green,
    Opacity = 0.5
}; 
Panel.SetZIndex(path, 2);
canvas.Children.Add(path);
```

However my `Canvas` does not display anything.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to use a [PathGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry(v=vs.110).aspx) with the polygon points?

Comment: @Clemens I' new with WPF. I will check PathGeometry class. Thank you for your recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should force the geometry to be rendered before you it to the `Canvas`. You can do this by calling the `Arrange` and `Measure` methods of the `Polygon`:

```
Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
polygon.Points = new PointCollection { new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 100), new Point(150, 150) };
polygon.Arrange(new Rect(canvas.RenderSize));
polygon.Measure(canvas.RenderSize);
var path = new Path
{
    Data = polygon.RenderedGeometry,
    Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    Fill = Brushes.Green,
    Opacity = 0.5
};
Panel.SetZIndex(path, 2);
canvas.Children.Add(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using a Polygon element to define the Geometry of a Path.

Instead directly create a `PathGeometry` like this:

```
var figure = new PathFigure
{
    StartPoint = new Point(0, 0),
    IsClosed = true
};

figure.Segments.Add(new PolyLineSegment
{
    Points = new PointCollection { new Point(0, 100), new Point(150, 150) },
    IsStroked = true
});

var geometry = new PathGeometry();
geometry.Figures.Add(figure);

var path = new Path
{
    Data = geometry,
    Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    Fill = Brushes.Green,
    Opacity = 0.5
};
```

Or directly create a Geometry from a string using [Path Markup Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var path = new Path
{
    Data = Geometry.Parse("M0,0 L0,100 150,150Z"),
    Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    Fill = Brushes.Green,
    Opacity = 0.5
};
```